# What's wrong with my Ficus tree?

Tags: indoors

All the leaves have fallen off of my Ficus tree.   Will they grow back?   What would cause the leaves to turn yellow and fall off?

Comment: How old is it? What kind of substrate does it root in? Where does its pot stand? In what zone do you live? Can you provide an image?

Comment: Fruiting fig or foliage fig, houseplant or outdoors, how long have you had it?

Comment: Ficus are TOUGH plants yet super sensitive to change.  Have you moved it recently?  They will easily shed all their leaves and it can either mean death or they just might be healthy enough to come back.  Like deciduous trees for winter?  There are signals, shorter day length, cooler temperatures and deciduous trees drop all of their leaves.  Yours I am assuming is indoors and something recently changed.  Please send a picture and get it back to whatever environment it was used to.  Let's see your pot, what kind of soil, what are your watering methods, fertilizer?

Comment: You might want to read the sidenote from [this answer](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/576/how-to-prevent-my-ficus-plant-from-growing-new-branches-low/589)

Answer (score 1):

Very likely they'll grow back. Ficus are well known for throwing hissy fits and dropping all their leaves at the slightest change in environment, or if you look at them funny. They're very finicky.

Find a tiny branch you can cut off, see if it's dead (brown) inside or has a thin green layer. If it's still green be patient, it'll come back. Keep giving it water and light.

If the branch is dead, keep working back to larger branches till you find one that's alive. How far you must go back to find life will give you a good sense of how well the tree is doing.